# How are these two conditions equivalent?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I'm reading an article and I quote the author here :

The condition $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^t L(n) \operatorname{Pr}\left(|X|>n^{1 / r}\right)<\infty$ is equivalent to the moment condition $E\left[|X|^{(t+1) r} L(X)\right]<\infty$.

$t \geq 0, 0<r <2$, $X$ is an arbitrary random variable and $L(\cdot)$ is a slowly varying function but shouldn't matter here, I know that generally for positive random variables we got $\mathrm{E}[X] \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{P}(X>n)$

but it doesn't seem to me that there's a an obvious way of arranging terms to get that equivalence of conditions.

if somebody can help that'll be cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\Pr\left(\lvert X\rvert>n^{1/r}\right)=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \Pr\left(k^{1/r}<\lvert X\rvert\leqslant (k+1)^{1/r}\right)$, hence
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^t L(n) \operatorname{Pr}\left(|X|>n^{1 / r}\right)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^t L(n)\sum_{k=n}^\infty  \Pr\left(k^{1/r}<\lvert X\rvert\leqslant (k+1)^{1/r}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \Pr\left(k^{1/r}<\lvert X\rvert\leqslant (k+1)^{1/r}\right) \sum_{n=1}^k n^t L(n).
\end{align}
Since $L(\cdot)$ is slowly varying, the exists constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that for each $\ell\geqslant 1$, $$c_1 2^{\ell(t+1)}L(2^\ell)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{2^\ell} n^t L(n)\leqslant c_2 2^{\ell(t+1)}L(2^\ell)$$
then we can conclude.